# how to reset a view pane in cinema 4d

Tags: viewport, reset, cinema-4d

I am new to cinema 4d and I built a model which is easily viewable in my right, top, and front viewports, but in perspective view I can't see anything, and I can't figure out how to reset or recenter the view. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be useful too:
You can press "o" to center the selected Object in the current viewport

Answer (score 5):

Besides the undo command, there is also "Frame Default" command in the edit menu of the view panel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't quite figure out a "reset" button, but what I did realize is that cinema4d has two styles of undo - one for actions undertaken within the program, and one for the views themselves, so I was able to successfully undo using the viewpane undo mode.